# É aconselhável ter uma tabela de Usuários se relacionando com outras?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

sou iniciante em desenvolvimento de sistemas, e gostaria de saber se a tabela de usuários do sistema poderia estabelecer relações com outras tabelas, como por exemplo, a tabela de empresa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, sem problemas.

Por exemplo, eu poderia associar usuários a empresas usando chaves estrangeiras:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPRESA (
    EMPRESA_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    -- Coloque aqui as colunas que você gostaria que EMPRESA tivesse
)

CREATE TABLE USUARIO (
    USUARIO_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EMPRESA_ID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EMPRESA(EMPRESA_ID),
    NOME VARCHAR(255),
    -- Coloque aqui as colunas que você gostaria que USUARIO tivesse
);
```

As associações também podem ser feitas para outras tabelas. Tudo depende do objetivo desejado.

Note que não usei uma sintaxe SQL em específico. A ideia é apenas ilustrar o que pode ser feito.

Comment: É que eu quero fazer um sistema em que o usuário se relacione com a tabela de chamado e empresa. Aí fiquei na dúvida se desmembrava essa tabela, pois nela vai conter o usuário, tipo de usuário e campos afins, para alguma outra tabela específica.

Comment: No seu lugar, faria a tabela de chamados se relacionar com empresa e com usuário. Nada impede que isso seja feito na modelagem.

Comment: Modelei a tabela de chamados se relacionando com funcionários(contendo os campos para login) e usuarios(contendo todas as informações da empresa e os campos senha, e login). Caso eu queira adicionar uma tabela de comentários, como eu modelaria? Visto que o comentário pode ser feito pela usuário e por um funcionário, e as chaves estrangeiras não podem ser nulas? Por exemplo, como eu sei que foi o usuário quem comentou, e não um funcionário?

Comment: Isto já seria conteúdo para uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Vou fazer! Obrigado pela atenção